# JSON templates in python?

Tags: json, templates, yaml

I want to be able to specify a template in json / yaml and fill in values based on context:

```
root:
  child: {{child_value}}
  other_child: 1
```

Then in my code I could run:

`output = format("template.yaml", context=dict(child_value=1))`

Normally templating systems don't really work that well because they encode two and from strings. Ideally you would want something that is *aware* of the yaml structure (this appears to be the approach used internally within docker-compose for example. I have come across libraries with this mindset of xml before)

Can I do this - preferrably with something standard?

## Research

- I know that docker-compose does internaly. This appears to be hand coded in docker compose. [code in docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/0bea52b18dda3de8c28fcfb0c80cc08b8950645e/compose/config/interpolation.py%7D%7D)
- I suspect that tools like helm do this.

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: @flyx How do I do the thing I want to do....

Comment: If it helps, I'm a coauthor of a tool/library that does this sort of thing. https://github.com/con2/emrichen/

Comment: Is your question is "what is wrong with my `format()` call"? Or is it "which templating engine should I use" (which is off-topic on StackOverflow)?

Comment: @flyx I kind of assumed the things wrong with `.format` and other forms of template engine,  could be taken as given. We could get into that issue. I am aware questions of "which is best" are beyond scope. The question is more are any suitable... Let me address the problem with standard templating systems in the question.

Comment: @AKX that is precisely what I'm after, thanks. Unfortunately my reviewers are going to veto your projects based on the lack of stars. Which sucks. If I come across this projects again in another context I may well use your projects. I'll star it as well.

Hopefully this question will allow others who have similar problems to find your repo, use it, star it and eventually your project will have enough starts to get more acceptance. Although... I'm not really sure that being an open source projects maintainer is fun! 

Maybe some open source project will use it an pay you to maintain it :D

Comment: @AttRigh Thanks. I have to say that's a weird review process since the stars metric is easily artificially inflatable...

Comment: @AKX I mean the real measure is "how maintained is this" and "has this been used enough to shake out the common bugs" and "are people going to motivated to fix issues" as well as "how easy would it be to push vulnerabilities into this library and for us to not detect".

You are correct that stars could be inflated. I would suggest you ignore anything I have to say as I'm just a random person on the internet. It looks like a nice utility that people are finding useful....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically three ways to do it:

#### Process the input with a templating engine *before* feeding it to the YAML parser

This is your *anything goes* approach: You can use any templating engine you want, from the standard `format` over minimal things like mustache up to fully-featured solutions like Jinja. As you stated, the downside to this is that the engine is unaware of the YAML structure. This needs manual adjustment when pasting complex values (which must be YAML-serialized) and multi-line strings (which must be indented properly).

This approach is used for example in Ansible, SaltStack (both Jinja) and Helm (Go's `text/template`).

#### Process the input with a templating engine *after* feeding it to the YAML parser

This usually means that you parse your YAML with the failsafe schema, producing only lists, dicts and strings. Then you process each string with a templating engine or some other kind of processor that could, for example, refer to other parts of your YAML data.

The problem with this approach is that you need to get your template's syntax through the YAML parser as content. Because of this, it would be ill-advised to use syntax like `{{child_value}}` since that will be read as two nested mappings by the YAML processor.

Another problem is that it is unclear when and how to check validity of the input data: You can't do it when parsing the YAML because you will have unprocessed templating expressions in there, but you may get into problems if your templating solution allows to refer to other values in the structure and those have not been type-checked yet.

This approach is in used for example in Azure Pipelines which uses as syntax `${{...}}}` and `$[...]`.

#### Use YAML Tags as templating engine

You can register custom contructors to allow something like

```yaml
root:
  child: !var child_value
  other_child: 1
```

The custom constructor for the tag `!var` would then fetch the value named `child_value`. The good part about this is that you don't need an additional templating engine and your file needs to adhere to only one syntax. However it is pretty talkative and I have seldom seen this in action.

I don't really see any drawback compared to the previous approach (it has the same problem with references though), I can only assume that this is exotic simply because a lot of people do not really know about YAML tags.

#### Conclusion

The first approach is simpler for putting scalar (string/numeric/etc) values in certain places. The other approaches are better for injecting complex values since you can inject them as Python values instead of generating YAML substructures for them. There is no perfect solution and it depends on your use-case which way you go.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've been going down option 2. It's about 75 lines of code. I've got some hacks for looping - which I would prefer to outsource to someone else rather than implement myself but... oh well. The third approach is pretty interesting.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm really after is something that will give me looping constructs within the yaml. I didn't really specify thisi n the question.

Comment: @AttRigh Loops are tricky because they generate structure. The first approach will be simpler because the others do not have an obvious solution for "after these two fixed list items, add some more using a loop".

Comment: Yeah. It just seems kind of ugly having two langauges (yaml and templates) that don't line up and having it be possible / easy to produce invalid json. Then again... this is sthe way that things have cone for html... though that's a bit different. 

I think for small projects regular template (jinja) and just not getting it wrong might be the way to go... because people can't be bothered to learn your templating system.

Comment: The third approach is exactly what https://github.com/con2/emrichen/ does (as linked in the original post's comments)...

Comment: @AKX Nice! I never heard of it. So in emrichen, the solution to the loop problem I described above seems to be `!Concat [[static, items], !For […], [more, static items]]` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hmm... I'm wondering if python `eval` is the way to go. In the same style as django config files.

Comment: This is the sort of stuff that lisp is pretty good at because the code and data structure is pretty similar looking, and also there isn't really an arbitrary line between "staements" and expressions like there is in python.

Comment: @AttRigh There is a line between *input being data* vs *input evaluating to data*. YAML is the first, while templating languages are the second. Transitioning this line always has drawbacks, like for example, your emrichen cannot use the sequence generated by `!For` directly as input for another command. I once suggested *annotations* as new entities in a future YAML 1.3 to cross that line in the language itself; I did write an experimental implementation and docs can be found [here](https://ada.yaml.io/trans/). My takeaway was that this is too complex and would only hinder standard adoption.

Comment: For what it's worth, I decided to go for a python file as the template itself.